# Which code is better to find the first recurring alphabet in a string?

Tags: python, algorithm, search

The first code is:

```
 string = "DBCABA"
 #computing the first recurring alphabet
 def compute_reccuring():
     for a in string:
         var = string.count(a)
         if var > 1:
            final = str(a) 
        print(str(final) + " is repeated first")
        break
```

The second code is:

```
def recurring():
    counts = {}
    for a in string:
        if a in counts:
           print(a)
        else:
           counts[a] = 1
```

Both of these codes work but I don't know which one is better in performance.

Comment: Create a big enough string and try to test the performance.

Comment: `string.count` is an implicit loop. Also, in the second example the `if a in counts..` probably should be outside / previously terminated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: So it looks to me that the first one is `O(n^2)` (for each `a in string` you walk the whole string again in the `.count(a)`), while the second one is `O(n)` since you're using a `dict` (`counts`) that has a constant access time of `O(1)` so, just by looking at the code I'd say the 2nd one is "better" However, in the second one you need to keep a `dict` in memory, so it could take more memory... Depends on what you consider **better**... Faster? Less memory?

Comment: The recipe suggested at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-first-repeated-character-in-a-string/ is virtually your second option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a timer function as below and decorate your function with it and see the result yourself.

```
import time                                                

def timeme(method):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        startTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        endTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        print(endTime - startTime,'ms')
        return result

    return wrapper
```

You can then use this function as decorator for your function. Something like this:

```
@timeme
def recurring():
```

Comment: thanks. its shows the time for these two functions, but what about the memory?

Comment: May be you can experiment with [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check time taken by your script to run.

```
import time
start = time.time()
'''
Your Code

'''
end = time.time()

print(start - end)
```